# Thrown object cannot be caught in a multi-threaded solution

Tags: exception, c++11, constructor, raii, stdthread

I have a RAII class that solves a problem in an inner thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

struct solution_using_thread {
    solution_using_thread()
     : alive_(true), thread_() {
        thread_ = thread([this]() {
            while(alive_);
        });
    }
    ~solution_using_thread() {
        alive_ = false;
        thread_.join();
    }
private:
    bool alive_;
    thread thread_;
};

int main() {
    cout << 0 << endl;
    try {
        solution_using_thread solution;
        throw 1;
    } catch (int i ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << 2 << endl;
}
```

After creating an instance of it, the main happens to throw an exception. The problem is in some of the executions, the output is:

```
0
```

when it always should have been:

```
0
1
2
```

In [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86c98437b2dacea1), it is always only `0`.

What am I missing here?

PS: Sorry, for the ambiguous title. Please do not hesitate to suggest a better one for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that the thread will (eventually) see the updated value of `alive_`. But that's not guaranteed. Objects without synchronisation are *not* guaranteed to be made visible to other threads in any finite amount of time. It's possible the value of `alive_` is cached somewhere and never updated.

You need some synchronisation to make it work—either use a mutex or another synchronisation primitive, or make `alive_` atomic. Here's a [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8db7759f0010dba9) of the latter:

```
#include <atomic>

struct solution_using_thread {
    solution_using_thread()
     : alive_(true), thread_() {
        thread_ = thread([this]() {
            while(alive_);
        });
    }
    ~solution_using_thread() {
        alive_ = false;
        thread_.join();
    }
private:
    atomic<bool> alive_;
    thread thread_;
};
```

Without any synchronisation, the program has Undefined Behaviour, because the two threads enter a data race over `alive_`.

Comment: Before accepting your answer, can you please explain why the stack unwinding does not block at ``thread_.join()`` (in the original code)?

Comment: @bmm Added mention that without sync, it's UB, so anything can happen (including not blocking).