# Understanding why race condition happens when only one thread does the write operation

Tags: exception, c++11, race-condition, raii, stdatomic

I recently asked "[Thrown object cannot be caught in a multi-threaded solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811830/thrown-object-cannot-be-caught-in-a-multi-threaded-solution)" and got the correct answer which works perfectly. However, I am still confused why there can be a race condition when only one thread does the write operation. Let me paste the original problematic code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

struct solution_using_thread {
    solution_using_thread()
     : alive_(true), thread_() {
        thread_ = thread([this]() {
            while(alive_);
        });
    }
    ~solution_using_thread() {
        alive_ = false;
        thread_.join();
    }
private:
    bool alive_;
    thread thread_;
};

int main() {
    cout << 0 << endl;
    try {
        solution_using_thread solution;
        throw 1;
    } catch (int i ) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << 2 << endl;
}
```

Sometimes the output is only

```
0
```

According to the linked question, if I instead use member `atomic<bool> alive_`, the output becomes as expected

```
0
1
2
```

Now, I am trying to reason why member `bool alive_` causes Undefined Behavior.

**Case 1 (Happy ending):**

- Variable `solution` is initialized:

  - `solution_using_thread`'s default constructor sets `alive_` to `true` in the main thread.
  - The thread starts and the value of `alive_` happens to be `true` in the second thread. So thread execution is stuck in the `while` loop.
  - Before constructor returns, the second thread has already been started.
- We `throw 1`.

  - The destructor of `solution` is called. The value of `alive_` is `true` in the main thread.
  - `thread.join()` blocks until the value of `alive_` is synchronized with the second thread.
  - After some finite amount of delay `alive_` is synchronized, the while loop terminates, the second thread finishes, the `thread_.join()` returns and stack unwinding is happily completed.
- The output is `0 1 2`

**Case 2 (Not desired, but at least not 'Undefined Behavior'):**

- Variable `solution` is initialized:

  - `solution_using_thread`'s default constructor sets `alive_` to `true` in the main thread.
  - The thread starts and the value of `alive_` happens to be `false` in the second thread. So thread execution ends immediately.
  - Before constructor returns, the second thread have already been started.
- We `throw 1`

  - `thread.join()` returns immediately because the thread has already finished.
- The output is `0 1 2`

Obviously there is at least one more case in which it prints only `0`. Can you describe that case?

Comment: General rule: Don't try to understand undefined behaviour. And absolutely don't try to second-guess and "work around" it. [Recommended video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHCLkb1vKaY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard says that if multiple threads access a variable and at least one access is a write, then if the variable isn't atomic and the operations aren't ordered, there is a data race, and a program with a data race has undefined behaviour.

Knowing these rules, the compiler can assume that a non-atomic variable is not modified out of order (since otherwise *any* program is a valid interpretation of your source code); in your example code, this means that the compiler can simply assume that `alive_` never changes inside the busy loop -- though by the way, a non-terminating loop like that is itself undefined behaviour.